# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have problem and please help me

I'm getting error in this laravel php file on line 15.
what could be wrong?

```
public function tambahdata() {  

    $data = array(
        'nama' => Input::get('nama'),
        'alamat' => Input::get('alamat'),
        'kelas' => Input::get('kelas'),
    );

    DB::table('siswa')->insert($data);
    return Redirect::to('/read')->with('message','Tambah data berhasil');
}
```

Comment: Post full code of the file..........

Comment: it means that your curly braces aren't paired properly; you've got one-too many `}` somewhere. But it's not in the code you've shown us; it's probably somewhere in the code immediately preceding it.

Comment: Proper code indentation helps find and better still helps stop this happening [Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Error is not in the code you showed us.

Comment: Errors usually have line numbers and file names. The function looks fine, so what code precedes it?

Comment: If this function is not contained in a class you would get that error, even if all your braces were matched up properly. `public` is only valid within a class, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two braces before the method declaration, meaning that php interpreter thinks that the class is finished, it isn't expecting more method declarations.

---

You probably have something like this:

```
<?php
class Something {
    public function someMethod() {
        // Some code
    }} // <------- An extra closing brace. PHP thinks that the class is over and isn't expecting the 'public' keyword, which the next thing in your code

    public function tambahdata() {  
        $data = array(
                'nama' => Input::get('nama'),
                'alamat' => Input::get('alamat'),
                'kelas' => Input::get('kelas'),
            );

        DB::table('siswa')->insert($data);
        return Redirect::to('/read')->with('message','Tambah data berhasil');
    }
}
```